# How to balance server response time with high traffic?

Tags: server

I have Hostgator basic plan of dedicated server. When in Peak time the response time of my website goes very high for REST API and it does not respond properly within time the loader run for a long time and show The 500 status code, or Internal Server Error, means that server cannot process the request for an unknown reason.

When I hit the same API at night it send response immediately.

My server is with APACHE and web-services are build in core PHP.

Comment: Please help me out what I can do now?